# Numbers Are Being Reformatted In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having issues with MySQL changing the values of numerical data. It happens upon form submission and when outputting to Excel. ID numbers like this 911001001235848 are coming out like this 9.1100100123585E+14. Any suggestions as to what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure it's mySQL's doing, and not PHP's?

Comment: ^ or Excel for that matter. Anyway, what's the column's datatype?

Comment: If it was mysql doing it, you'd see it when running the same query manually in the mysql monitor. Most likely it's excel.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft's documentation, you should ensure numeric values consisting of 12 or more digits are of type `string` and prefixed with an apostrophe to retain the original value. Below is an example of the above mentioned, followed by its supporting documentation.

```
"personId","personName","randomNumber"
1,"John Doe","'911001001235848"
2,"Jane Doe","'848532100100911"
```

**Notice that the "randomNumber" column values are double quoted and prefixed with an apostrophe.**

[Text or number converted to unintended number format in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214233)

Comment: exactly this, excel kills large numbers even if you format the column to display numbers out to 16 digits it will just change anything after it's cutoff to 0. You shouldn't have to format the column as text though, just leave it at auto detect and include the `'` at the beginning. You are however screwed on aggregating those numbers if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The user inputs the being and last of a sequence and the script fills the numbers in between. This is the PHP script I am using to input the numbers into MySQL and it only inputs the first number then the messed up number second. Small numbers work great but I need to be able to input 15 digit numbers.

```
$date  = date("m-d-Y");
$nstart=$_REQUEST['startid'];
$nend = $_REQUEST['endid'];
$doc = $_REQUEST['doc'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];


for ($i = $nstart; $i <= $nend; $i++) 
{ 
$query = "INSERT INTO petdb (doc,phone, userid, reg_date) VALUES ('$doc','$phone','     $i', '$date')"; 
mysql_query($query, $con); 
} 
mysql_close();
```